# .Net DateTime fiscal Quarter

Tags: .net, datetime

Does anyone know how to construct a DateTime in .NET to be the first day of the current quarter?

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on how you define a quarter.

Comment: How many different ways can you define a fiscal quarter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public DateTime GetCurrentQuarter(DateTime date)
{
    int startingMonthOfQuarter = (((date.Month - 1) / 3) * 3) + 1;

    return new DateTime(date.Year, startingMonthOfQuarter, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        var year = currentTime.Year;
        DateTime[] quarterStarts = {new DateTime(year, 1, 1), new DateTime(year, 4, 1), new DateTime(year, 7, 1), new DateTime(year, 10, 1)};
        var currentStart = quarterStarts.Where(s => s < currentTime).Last();
```

Comment: This is going to fail if it's called exactly at 12:00 midnight on January 1.  It's also going to fail if the year changes at some point after `quarterStarts` is defined.  You probably want to modify your test to include just the month and day.

Answer (score 1):

@yogesh is right, here's what I use in a sql sp:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_startOfQtr](@dt DATETIME) 
RETURNS DATETIME AS  
BEGIN 
    declare @ret DATETIME
    declare @qtr int

    set @qtr = ((month(@dt)-1)/3)+1
    set @ret = cast(str(@qtr * 3 - 2) + '/1/' + str(year(@dt)) as DATETIME)
    return @ret
END
```